# How to only allow predetermined values in textbox within an html form

Tags: html, forms

I have a list of values that I only want to be allowed to be entered into a text box within an html form for the action to take place.  The action is taking the end user to a certain web page.  But I want the end user to only enter certain values.  They can be allowed to enter something else but they'll receive a notice/warning that they've entered an incorrect code.

Three of the predetermined list of values let's say would be something like this

GGG01, OOO03 and MTM02

As I said, and end user should be allowed to enter anything but only when they enter one of those three codes should they be taken to the specific web page.  I've tried validation scripts and nothing seems to be working.  I'm missing something here and I bet it's so easy.

Here's what I tried but the password field isn't working properly.  Please help.  Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html
   PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>
      Example for Validator
    </title>
    <style type="text/css" xml:space="preserve">
BODY, P,TD{ font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt }
A{font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica, sans-serif;}
B { font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 12px;   font-weight : bold;}
.error_strings{ font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px; color:#660000;}
</style><script language="JavaScript" src="gen_validatorv4.js"
    type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" name="myform" id="myform">
      <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            First Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Last Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="LastName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            EMail
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="Email" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Password
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="pwd1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Address
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="Address"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Country
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="Country">
            <option value="" selected="selected">
              [choose yours]
            </option>
            <option value="008">
              Albania
            </option>
            <option value="012">
              Algeria
            </option>
            <option value="016">
              American Samoa
            </option>
            <option value="020">
              Andorra
            </option>
            <option value="024">
              Angola
            </option>
            <option value="660">
              Anguilla
            </option>
            <option value="010">
              Antarctica
            </option>
            <option value="028">
              Antigua And Barbuda
            </option>
            <option value="032">
              Argentina
            </option>
            <option value="051">
              Armenia
            </option>
            <option value="533">
              Aruba
            </option></select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"></td>
          <td>
            <div id="myform_errorloc" class="error_strings">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"></td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    xml:space="preserve">//<![CDATA[
//You should create the validator only after the definition of the HTML form

    function DoCustomValidation()
{
  var frm = document.forms["myform"];
  if(frm.pwd1.value != frm.pwd2.value)
  {
    sfm_show_error_msg('The Password and verified password does not match!',frm.pwd1);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}

  frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction(DoCustomValidation);
//]]></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can’t use the most obvious solution to the original problem, namely a `select` element? Or a little less obvious, but often better, solution: a set of radio buttons with the same `name` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking it that we're looking for options without connecting to a database (that would make the answer longer). To start you off on a direction and one particular option (which might not be the most favorable or efficient option for your situation):

Firstly, `form` tag should have a `method` attribute.

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="POST" name="myform" id="myform">
```

then you can access it and make conditional statements later on. For example, if a person typed in a certain word that you wanted in the LastName section and submitted it, you can let it go confirm.php which would include the following script (which would evaluate if the user put in a certain value or not, and depending on the value, the user would be redirected to a different page):

```
if ($_POST['LastName']=="GGG01"){
    header("nameofnewwebsite.php");
}else{
    header("nameofanotherwebsite.php");
}
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested Mike_Moto but it's not working.  Try it out here http://www.notchsters.com/test.html

And you can download the files here - I probably did something wrong.
http://www.notchsters.com/Archive.zip

I appreciate the effort.

Comment: I think I'd like to use java script for this one because if you go to http://www.notchsters.com/ and in the upper right hand corner you'll see a place where you can enter your code - I would like an error warning to occur right on that page http://www.notchsters.com/ if an end user enters an incorrect code. And if the end user enters a correct code - let's say one of these three GGG01, OOO03, MTM02 then they'd go to the page that I want them to go to.